# npm unpublish 403 Err

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-publish

I accidentally published wrong package. (less than 24 hours)
So I tried to delete that version with this command:

```
npm unpublish adm-trv@1.0.2
```

But I got this error:

```
npm ERR! unpublish Failed to update data
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "unpublish" "adm-trv@1.0.2"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3
npm ERR! code E500

npm ERR! "adm-trv status = 403" : adm-trv
```

I tried to login again with `npm login` but nothing changed.

**My system:**
OS X El Capitan
node V6.2.1
npm V3.9.3

Comment: Contacting support@npmjs.com will help you unpublish your npm, according to this http://blog.npmjs.org/post/141905368000/changes-to-npms-unpublish-policy